# Is there a way to store values obtained in a previous computation?

Tags: performance-tuning

This question may be badly worded but I have some commands which are defined recursively, call these $x[n]$, which give a list as a solution. I then have a function, say $f$, which is applied to these lists. f takes as input a the $x[n]$ a fixed number $z$ and applies the function to it, so it will be something like $f[x[n],z]$. What I use this code for is the check various $z$ values but the x[n] stays the same. Is there some way to get mathematica to remember the $x[n]$'s that it computes instead of recomputing the $x[n]$'s each time which I believe is what it currently does.

The code is below:

```
c0 = -1;
f0[z_] := z^2 + c0;
list1 = Table[4 E^(j*I*Pi/256), {j, 0, 512}];
ToComplex[x_] := x.{1, I};
fr[z1_, z2_] := z /. FindRoot[f0[z] == z2, {z, z1}] 

lift[z_, path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, z, path1], 1]

liftp[path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, 1, path1], 1]

liftm[path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, -1, path1], 1]


x[n_] := Map[ToComplex, ReIm[list1]] /; n == 0
x[n_] := Join[ liftp[x[n - 1]], liftm[x[n - 1]]] /; n > 0
```

Comment: In your definition of x[n], use "memoization":  for example, for the Fibbonacci series, x[n_]:=x[n]=x[n-1]+x[n-2]    Then it only does the calculation once.

Comment: Re @bills comment, see [`Functions That Remember Values They Have Found`](tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions#202640595)

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work, but I think there is a problem because I have a function defined with a condition. The x[0] is just a list but the x[n]'s use this. Using the memory function does not like this. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: Edit your question to show a minimal concrete example that demonstrates the issue and the code that you are using.

Comment: I have added this and also tried to fix the code but this time I get a Recursion Limit error

Comment: The line `x[n_] := Map[ToComplex, ReIm[list1]] /; n == 0` should be written `x[0] := Map[ToComplex, ReIm[list1]]`. Can I ask why you first do `ReIm` and then `Dot` these with `{1, I}`? That does not make sense to me. In any case, your dimensions are flipped in the sense that the result of `ReIm[list1]` has `Dimensions` 2 x 513, but you need 513 x 2 to have pairs for your `ToComplex`. Wrap a `Transpose` around the `ReIm` to fix.

Comment: I'm not a coder by background so I am trying to fit the code to the mathematics, probably in a very inefficient way. The ReIm is to convert from exponential form of a complex number to Euclidean and then to a complex number for the lift command to work. I'm not sure if it works with the exponential form. This has been written and edited over many documents to get it to work so there may be some historical bad code remaining.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `FindRoot` does not care whether we see the number as exponential form or Euclidean form ;) `FindRoot` is a numerical method, so it will use ordinary computer representations of complex numbers, which I guess are pairs of floats represented in binary.

Comment: Anyway, the command to turn exponential form into Euclidean form for complex numbers in Mathematica is `ComplexExpand` :) E.g. `ComplexExpand[ 4 E^((I Pi)/256)]` gives `4 Cos[Pi/256]+4 I Sin[Pi/256]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ToComplex` and `ReIm` parts are not necessary for this code since the numbers will be fed to `FindRoot` anyway, which is a numerical method that does not care about the visible representation of complex numbers. With this in mind, the following should work.

```
c0 = -1;
f0[z_] := z^2 + c0;
list1 = 4 E^(Range[0,512]*I*Pi/256);
fr[z1_, z2_] := z /. FindRoot[f0[z] == z2, {z, z1}]

liftp[path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, 1, path1], 1]

liftm[path1_] := Drop[FoldList[fr[#1, #2] &, -1, path1], 1]


x[0] = list1
x[n_] := x[n] = Join[liftp[x[n - 1]], liftm[x[n - 1]]]
```

Notice the following aspects:

1. Multiplication and exponentiation are `Listable` in Mathematica. That means that we don't have to create a `Table` in order to produce `list1`. Simply put the `Range` of `j` values into the expression and it works! `Range` is somewhat similar to `linspace` in MATLAB/Python.
2. You never call `lift` in your code, so I removed it.
3. The base case for your recursion is just that `x[0] = list1`, so *we write exactly that*. No need for a pattern `n_ /; n == 0` or anything complicated like that. Also note that we use `=` and not `:=`. The reason is that `list1` is not going to change in the recursion, so we can evaluate the RHS immediately, instead of every time `x[0]` is called.
4. Finally, the memoization that answers the question in the title about a function remembering its values. This is the `x[n_] := x[n] = ...` part. Notice also here that we don't have to say `/; n > 0`. The reason is that Mathematica will (almost always) apply more specific rules before applying more general ones, and the pattern `x[0]` is more specific than `x[n_]`. But if you *want* to specify `n > 0` for readability, I suggest putting this constraint on the LHS, like so: `x[n_ /; n > 0] := ...`. That way, if `n > 0` is not true, we don't even have to parse the LHS.

If we now execute `x[2]`, we will get a list with 2052 elements after a few milliseconds. If we then try to execute `x[2]` *again*, the list appears instantly, because Mathematica remembers the result. But please understand that if we now execute lots of different `x[i]`, Mathematica is told to remember **all** the results, so this might eat quite a bit of RAM, especially since the lists double in lenght for each `n`.

Comment: Thank you for this! I implemented some of these changes and managed to reduce computation time by 11 minutes in one case, and I imagine this will improve further with future computations that use this initial data. I tried removing the `ReIm` and `ToComplex` from the code but this caused issues with the later code and gave incorrect results so I think it is somehow necessary. Perhaps in time I will look and see if I can remove this and improve the code further. Thank you for you help!

Comment: Glad it helped! Since it did, please consider upvoting the answer ;) If a better answer does not arrive within a reasonable amount of time, you can also accept it.